# Springboot Webflux jackson deserialization not working

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, deserialization, spring-webflux

I have a springboot server in which I'musing webflux. I overrode the default Jackson ObjectMapper by setting a default type resolver, but when Flux encoder is not working as expected:

```
// Configuration.java
@Configuration
public class Configuration {

  @Bean
  Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
    TypeResolverBuilder<?> typeResolver =
        new ObjectMapper.DefaultTypeResolverBuilder(DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL).init(Id.CLASS, null)
            .inclusion(As.PROPERTY);
    return jacksonObjectMapperBuilder -> jacksonObjectMapperBuilder
        .defaultTyping(typeResolver);

  }
}

// Controller.java
@RestController
public class Controller {

  @Autowired
  ObjectMapper mapper;

  @GetMapping(value = "/flux")
  public Flux<Boolean> getFlux()  throws Exception {
    System.err.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(true)); // prints "true" : OK
    return Flux.just(true); // Not returning "true" on the browser
  }
}
```

When I test the endpoint with a browser, I get the following:

> ["org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ReactiveTypeHandler$CollectedValuesList",[true]]

Obviously the deserialization is wrong, not only it shouldn't include the type (because boolean is a final class), but also the representation is wrong (included as an array).

When I remove the jackson configuration, I get on the browser **true** as an output which is correct

- Spring boot version: 2.1.2.RELEASE
- Java version: 8

Comment: I don't have much experiences with reactive project but should't you expect from Flux to emit a collection of single element by Flux.just?

Comment: Actually with Mono I don't have the same issue, but I posted the code above just to provide minimal code to reproduce the problem. in my app, I need to use Flux because I'm streaming endless booleans, and the problem is reproducible even when using Flux.just(true, false, false, true).

Comment: I have no idea what it is you want to solve? If it prints correct when you remove your strange configuration, then keep it removed 

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I need to keep the configuration because I'm using Jackson Polymorphic Deserialization elsewhere